Expected lifetime for replacement exhaust parts (centre silencer)
I have a Honda FR-V 2006 with a K20A9 engine.
The exhaust centre silencer box was replaced with a pattern brand (EuroFlo) four years ago (I'm not sure OEM was available), now I have an exhaust leak and my mechanic tells me that it's the centre silencer that's leaking at the joint with the rear section of the exhaust.
Is it normal that it should wear out so quickly? The original part of the exhaust still seems fine after 18 years and 100k miles but the new one failed after 4 years?
At least the pattern brand is still available, but it now costs double what it did four years ago!

It's hard to say for two major reasons. First, what is the silencer made out of? If it is made of of steel, they are going to go faster. If made of aluminum coated steel, a bit longer. If made of stainless steel, it's going to probably last the life of the vehicle. Secondly, what are normal conditions where you live? If you live in an area which sees severe weather during the winter months and they use salt to treat the roads, it's going to eat through metal faster and cause early demise.
There are plenty of reasons why a silencer might not last like you think it should, but in all honesty, there's no way to give you an "it should last xxx amount of years" answer.

Thanks for explaining that in detail. I don't know what it's made from. It's the EuroFlo EXHA3087 but I don't know what it is made from. The only information I have is what they advertise (http://www.euroflo-uk.com/img/EuroFlo%20Cutaway%20Panel.png).
I live in the UK, they do use salt to treat the roads during periods of low temperature, how much varies from year to year.
